# How do I create a Winform checklist box with multiple Items in it, pared with Textboxes for user Data Entry?

Tags: c#, winforms, checklistbox

I need a control which I can iterate through and change the items in it based on which option is selected in a separate combobox. Any direction would be helpful, thank you!.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utktY.png)

I can place each element separately, but then I'm not sure how to do that iteratively without a lot of work. I'm wondering if there is a better control for me to use.

Comment: What is exactly the problem? `ComboBox` change -> another list is shown, while others are hidden. Btw, a QoL suggestion: list header should be outside of scrollable area to be always present (like frozen column/rows in excel).

Comment: That's easy enough. I just cant figure out how to get a list of checkboxes pared with Textboxes for each row.

Comment: Perhaps a `ListView` is a better control or even `DataGridView`. Winforms is not very customization friendly (as opposed to WPF) , but for small lists filling `FlowLayoutPanel`/`TableLayoutPanel` containers manually with controls you need  may looks good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this is to use the `DataGridView` control and add sufficient `DataGridViewColumn`. In your example you could add `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` and `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` to your grid view. The only downside is that (at least to my knowledge) there is no easy way to add text directly to the checkbox cell but instead one could add another `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` to display that information.

How it would look like:

[image]

Just add a `DataGridView` in your designer then explicitly add three columns to it. In my example the first and third column is of type `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` whilst the middle column is of type `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`.

**Code**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addRow("Pavement", -0.25);
            addRow("End of way", 0);
            addRow("ELER", 0);
            addRow("ELEL", 0);
            addRow("ELEN", 0);
            addRow("ELEB", 0);

        }
```

```
 private void addRow(string pointCode, double offset)
        {
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell pcc = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cbc = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell ofc = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            pcc.Value = pointCode;
            ofc.Value = offset.ToString();
            cbc.Value = true; //Checkbox marked
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            row.Cells.Add(pcc);
            row.Cells.Add(cbc);
            row.Cells.Add(ofc);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```